# Why does Scipy sparse implementation returns incorrect number of singular values although dense one returns correct?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, svd

I am trying to evaluate Singular Value decompostion on my data set which has dimensions 1401375, 51. When I try to use scipy.linalg.svd, it gives me correct number of singular values (51) and all of them are correct (I checked against LAPACK). However, when I try using scipy.sparse.linalg.svds it gives an error:
ValueError: k must be between 1 and min(A.shape), k=51

```
  _, sigma, _ = sp.sparse.linalg.svds(A_s, k=51, return_singular_vectors='vh',which='LM')
_, sigma, _ = sp.linalg.svd(A_D, full_matrices=False,
                                            overwrite_a=True, check_finite=False,
                                            compute_uv=True)
```

I expect the sparse version to return 51 singular values, but it fails. When I lower the value of k to 50, it executes successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this on the scipy documentation for [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html), but k must be: 1 <= k < min(A.shape) so if your shape is 1401375, 51 then the min is 51 and k has to be less than that not less than or equal

Comment: Thanks. The error is then badly formulated, since between includes min(A.shape). Any reasons why it doesn't include min(A.shape)?

Comment: Python starts at 0 not 1, so if you count 0 to 50 it is actually 51 values. Inputting 51 would be 0 to 51 = 52 values, which would be greater than what you started with.